# Missing artifact spring data rest webmvc 2.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring, jpa, artifact

I am new to SPring . suddenly my pom.xml is throwing error after i update my proxy. It was working with the below

```
<spring.version>4.2.0.RC2</spring.version>
<spring-hateoas.version>0.19.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-hateoas.version>
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

<jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
```

Currently i am getting errors as

Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser:jar:2.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Kindly advise

EDIT

My pom.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>kar</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <description>Demo</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring.version>4.2.0.RC2</spring.version>
    <spring-hateoas.version>0.19.0.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

    <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
    <querydsl.version>3.6.5</querydsl.version>
    <springfox.version>2.0.3</springfox.version>

    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
      <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0.M1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.bedatadriven</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
      <version>jackson-datatype-jts-1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
  <groupId>kar</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <description>Demo</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring.version>4.2.0.RC2</spring.version>
    <spring-hateoas.version>0.19.0.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

    <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
    <querydsl.version>3.6.5</querydsl.version>
    <springfox.version>2.0.3</springfox.version>

    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
      <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0.M1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.bedatadriven</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
      <version>jackson-datatype-jts-1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Now i am getting error as **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/EnumTranslationConfiguration**

Comment: Put your entire POM.xml in main post.

Comment: Your POM is a giant mess, can you tell me what are you trying to achieve, this way I can help you clean it up, to remove unnecessary parts.

Comment: @WeareBorg I have a Spring application with rest end points JPA.  few entities have enum attribute defined.

Comment: @Jasmine did you figure it out? I have the same problem.